# cannot install phpPgAdmin - postgis and osgeo apache issues

Tags: osgeo, apache

i installed mapserver from osgeo and all went smooth

then, i wanted to install postgis, and the easiest way is with EnterpriseDB installation
http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload
(as said in this forum in another thread)

but i get an error saying that i need to have EnterpriseDB's apache installation in order to install phppgadmin.

in the FAQ of osgeo they have a section about this situation (say i install EnterpriseDB apache first)
[https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/FAQ#WhatifyouwanttowebenableOSGeo4WbutApacheisalreadyinstalledie:notbyOSGeo4W](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/FAQ#WhatifyouwanttowebenableOSGeo4WbutApacheisalreadyinstalledie%3anotbyOSGeo4W)

but it is missing the main explenation! :-\

can any one fill in the gap?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i figured it out and installed EnterpriseDB's apache on port 8080 and osgeo's apache on port 81.
thanks allot!